# SSRS 2008: Line chart Y-Axis scale issue

Tags: charts, ssrs-2008

After search of one week, finally decided to put my question in front of you all. Hope I will get some outcome from it.
Currently I am working on Line Chart. Following is the data which I need to bind to line chart.

```
JobStartDate  JobStartTime   JobEndTime
1/1/2015       01.00            02.30
1/2/2015       01.02            03.20
1/3/2015       01.01            03.40
1/4/2015       01.05            02.00
1/5/2015       22.03            23.30
1/6/2015       22.05            23.40
```

So, In above scenario Line chart looks like:

```
  11.00 PM |                          /////////                
  10.00 PM |                          ..........         
  ........ |                                               
  04.00 AM |              /                          
  03.00 AM |    /  /                                      
  02.00 AM |  /                /                        
  01.00 AM |  .....................                                                
  12.00 AM |______________________________________________                                          
           1/1/15 1/2/15 1/3/15 1/4/15 1/5/15 1/6/15
```

But it should be like :

```
  04.00 AM |              /                          
  03.00 AM |    /  /                                      
  02.00 AM |  /                /                        
  01.00 AM |  .....................                                                
  12.00 AM |
  11.00 PM |                          /////////////                
  10.00 PM |                          ............
  09.00 PM |______________________________________________                                          
           1/1/15 1/2/15 1/3/15 1/4/15 1/5/15 1/6/15
```

(Sorry As cant upload the image. So, Tried to show as above.)
In above figure (.) is StartTime and (/) is EndTime.

You can see that I am facing the problem of Y-Axis scaling.
Hope everyone understand my problem. Please let me know for more explanation.

Comment: I have tried setting Minimum and Maximum value for Y-Axis but does not work.

Comment: It looks like you have ticked properties for logarithmic scale. - ?

Comment: No. I have not ticked properties for logarithmic scale.